# Flutter Instagram 'Followed 'Private User Api for media downloading via URL link

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, instagram

Okay for now I manage to get media URL by copying the posted link from public Instagram users so that my app can get data(media URL) from ?__a=1(Json ) and download it with flutter downloader.

But right now I'm having an issue where I can't get media URL from "FOLLOWED" private Instagram users

I already able to get authorization code and exchange it with access token via Authorization Window with Instagram Basic Display. But from there onwards I don't know what to do since I cant find any endpoint that can get a copied link data(media URL) from another private user account like how I did with public.

I want the user using the app be able to get the content from another "FOLLOWED" user media content by a copy of a link.

There apps out there able to do that which published in store(apple & android) where they can download any media content public & private(login needed).